# Javascript doesn't work in VBnet when redirecting to another page

Tags: vb.net, webforms

please I'm confused, why doesn't this script come up?

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

```
Dim AlertMessage As String = "This is an alert"                 
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "alert", "alert('" & AlertMessage & "')", True)
Response.Redirect("AnotherPage.aspx")
```

It just redirects without popping the alert.
Help,
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you redirect on the server side (in code behind), the response to the browser will be just the redirect, no html or js or anything else gets sent, so the browser never gets that javascript. If you want to show the alert first, you need to do the redirect in javascript after the alert.